# In R, how can I merge two datasets (one baseline and one follow-up) while taking into account individuals lost to follow-up?

Tags: r, database, dplyr, data-manipulation

Thank you in advance for your help.

I have a baseline dataset of around 30000 individuals. Each individual has a unique ID number. I also have a follow-up dataset with the same people, with maybe 2000 individuals lost to follow-up.
I'm trying to merge these datasets, matching the data from both datasets for each ID number. For individuals who have been lost to follow-up, I would like to keep them in the merged dataset, but their row would probably need to contain a bunch of NAs since outcomes couldn't be measured in the follow-up dataset.

Is there a way in R to go about this?

(As a relatively new R user, I don't really know how to even begin approaching this problem. I have a feeling I'd need to use dplyr, but matching individuals from two datasets according to their ID and generating NAs for those who were lost to follow-up are beyond me. Any help or hints would be appreciated.)

Comment: FYI, some really good discussions on forming questions to be more _reproducible_: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info. Welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `merge` with the `all.x = TRUE` command - put the baseline data first then the follow up data second in the `merge` statement. For instance, say your baseline data is `bl` and follow up is `fu`, but you are missing the last 5 patients to follow up:

```
bl <- data.frame(id = 1:20,
                var_bl = letters[1:20])

fu <- data.frame(id = 1:15,
               var_fu = letters[1:15])

alldata <- merge(bl, fu, by = "id", all.x = TRUE)
```

Output:

```
   id var_bl var_fu
1   1      a      a
2   2      b      b
3   3      c      c
4   4      d      d
5   5      e      e
6   6      f      f
7   7      g      g
8   8      h      h
9   9      i      i
10 10      j      j
11 11      k      k
12 12      l      l
13 13      m      m
14 14      n      n
15 15      o      o
16 16      p   <NA>
17 17      q   <NA>
18 18      r   <NA>
19 19      s   <NA>
20 20      t   <NA>
```

Note for future reference there is an `all.y` (which would keep all obs in the second dataset (ie, `fu`)) and an `all` statement that would keep all obs in both)

Note the comments on your question by r2evans, but for convenience, one `dplyr` approach would be:

```
dplyrdata <- dplyr::left_join(bl, fu)
```

Which would output the same data as above.